# Why does this mysql stored procedure not execute the SELECT repeatedly

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

The following is in a stored procedure. My first foray.

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE snum TINYINT;

  SET snum = 1;
  WHILE snum <= 10 DO
    SELECT snum, PUR__LIST.LPUpdatedDateTime FROM PUR__LIST 
        WHERE PUR__LIST.StoreNum = snum
        ORDER BY PUR__LIST.LPUpdatedDateTime DESC
        LIMIT 1;
    SET snum = snum + 1;
  END WHILE;
END
```

I just want to execute the same statement 10 times, varying 1 parameter.

If I run the SQL manually from the CLI, (modulo replacing snum with the proper numbers), it works as expected.  If I call the stored procedure, it runs for snum = 1, then apparently exits the loop.

If I put a "SELECT snum" above the existing select, then it prints 1, and exits instead of printing all of them.

This has to be something trivial, but I've tried CONTINUE handlers, and all kinds of monkeying with it.  I've read the docs on if it's deterministic, I'm not using any kind of replication, and I normally do this kind of stuff in Perl, but figured I should learn more about it, hence this...

Any help appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: The MySQL command line tool should display each of the separate resultsets that are returned. It's not at all clear how you are determining that the procedure is "exiting the loop" after only one execution of the SELECT statement. If we are using Perl DBI, after we are done with the first resultset, we need to use `more_results` to get the next resultset.  http://search.cpan.org/~michielb/DBD-mysql-4.042/lib/DBD/mysql.pm#MULTIPLE_RESULT_SETS

Comment: There are 10 unique values for snum.  It prints the select for snum=1 and that's it, I don't get more results.  I have a perl script that does the same thing that generates all 10 lines, but I was trying to get familiar with using stored procedures, so figured it would be a simple one to implement.  But there should be 10 lines of output.

Comment: The stored procedure doesn't *print* anything. A stored procedure can return multiple resultsets. It's up to the client that calls the procedure to access and retrieve the rows from each resultset. The stored procedure in this question does not produce "10 lines of output". The procedure returns *ten* separate resultsets. Each resultset will contain (at most) one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Previously left as a comment on the question, repeated here:*

The MySQL command line tool should display each of the separate resultsets that are returned.

It's not at all clear how you are determining that the procedure is "exiting the loop" after only one execution of the SELECT statement.

If we are using Perl DBI, after we are done with the first resultset, we need to use `more_results` to get the next resultset.

Reference: http://search.cpan.org/~michielb/DBD-mysql-4.042/lib/DBD/mysql.pm#MULTIPLE_RESULT_SETS

---

A demonstration using the MySQL Command line client:

setup:

```
mysql> use test;
Database changed
mysql> CREATE TABLE `PUR__LIST`
    -> ( `StoreNum`          INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
    -> , `LPUpdatedDateTime` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '1970-01-02'
    -> , PRIMARY KEY (`StoreNum`,`LPUpdatedDateTime`)
    -> ) ENGINE=INNODB
    -> ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `PUR__LIST` (`StoreNum`, `LPUpdatedDateTime`) VALUES
    ->  (1,'2017-05-08 11:00')
    -> ,(1,'2017-05-08 12:00')
    -> ,(2,'2017-05-08 13:00')
    -> ,(2,'2017-05-08 14:00')
    -> ,(3,'2017-05-08 15:00')
    -> ,(3,'2017-05-08 16:00')
    -> ,(4,'2017-05-08 17:00')
    -> ,(4,'2017-05-08 18:00')
    -> ,(5,'2017-05-08 19:00')
    -> ,(5,'2017-05-08 20:00')
    -> ,(6,'2017-05-08 21:00')
    -> ,(7,'2017-05-08 22:00')
    -> ,(9,'2017-05-09 10:00')
    -> ;
Query OK, 13 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Records: 13  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

create stored procedure:

```
mysql> DELIMITER $$
mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE foo()
    -> BEGIN
    ->   DECLARE snum TINYINT;
    ->
    ->   SET snum = 1;
    ->   WHILE snum <= 10 DO
    ->     SELECT snum, PUR__LIST.LPUpdatedDateTime FROM PUR__LIST
    ->         WHERE PUR__LIST.StoreNum = snum
    ->         ORDER BY PUR__LIST.LPUpdatedDateTime DESC
    ->         LIMIT 1;
    ->     SET snum = snum + 1;
    ->   END WHILE;
    -> END$$
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER ;
```

execute stored procedure:

```
mysql> CALL foo;
+------+---------------------+
| snum | LPUpdatedDateTime   |
+------+---------------------+
|    1 | 2017-05-08 12:00:00 |
+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+------+---------------------+
| snum | LPUpdatedDateTime   |
+------+---------------------+
|    2 | 2017-05-08 14:00:00 |
+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+------+---------------------+
| snum | LPUpdatedDateTime   |
+------+---------------------+
|    3 | 2017-05-08 16:00:00 |
+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+------+---------------------+
| snum | LPUpdatedDateTime   |
+------+---------------------+
|    4 | 2017-05-08 18:00:00 |
+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+------+---------------------+
| snum | LPUpdatedDateTime   |
+------+---------------------+
|    5 | 2017-05-08 20:00:00 |
+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+------+---------------------+
| snum | LPUpdatedDateTime   |
+------+---------------------+
|    6 | 2017-05-08 21:00:00 |
+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+------+---------------------+
| snum | LPUpdatedDateTime   |
+------+---------------------+
|    7 | 2017-05-08 22:00:00 |
+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Empty set (0.00 sec)

+------+---------------------+
| snum | LPUpdatedDateTime   |
+------+---------------------+
|    9 | 2017-05-09 10:00:00 |
+------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Empty set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

That's *ten* separate resultsets. Two of the resultsets are empty (contain no rows), the others contain exactly one row. All of the resultsets are returned, but it's up to the client that calls the procedure to retrieve the rows from each of the returned resultsets.

Each execution of the `SELECT` statement adds another *resultset*. It does *not* append rows to a previous resultset.

Again, it's not at all clear what you are asking. Or how it is that you are determining that the procedure is exiting after the execution of only one SELECT statement.

Comment: OK, now it makes sense.  When I ran the stored proc from phpmyadmin, all I was getting was 1 line of results, hence my thinking it was exiting the loop after 1 iteration.  But working with the resultset makes more sense.  Like I said, first foray into stored procedures.  Learn by doing.  Thanks for the clarification.